# Best Way to Maintain Release Builds in Jenkins- How to Avoid disk occupancy by Release builds

Tags: maven, jenkins, release, release-management, autorelease

Currently we are locking the Release build numbers to keep it forever without getting deleted, but the issue here is each build size is around 3 to 5 GB. So overall release branches will have more than 50 builds.

Which is our bigger concern that it is occupying more space, as result we are facing slowness in jenkins loading or getting struck often.

Below is our product structure.

```
<component1>
<component2>
<component3>
<component4>

toolkit
```

Every branch will have all the above components, we are having separate jenkins jobs for every component.

and finally we run toolkit build in jenkins once all other components were build properly and pushed the artifacts to jfrog.

Toolkit-CI will pack the rpm's based on the script we have written. while packing it will download depandant jar, war and sar files from Jfrog.

We are having separate Release build, which people will trigger once the toolkit passed successfully.

Here one method we decided is tagging the current commits in every component when the RB is getting triggered.

So that we can delete the RB, in future if we need that particular RB, by the tag name (which will be there in every component) we can recreate the RB.

So jenkins disk space will not be occupied by Release builds.

If there is any other suggestions or any efficient methodoloy you are using in your org pls drop here.

Comment: `Currently we are locking the Release build numbers to keep it forever without getting deleted,` so why are you doing that...based on a release the state must be tagged in your version control and the artifacts must be deployed to a repository manager. Why keeping things in your Jenkins? What kind of information you have in there which is not stored anywhere else?

Comment: Why do you need to store them in Jenkins? That's weak. You can store external to Jenkins by many means (ArtifactDeployer, scp, etc.). At the very least make sure your artifacts have a manifest or BOM, with the tag or commit hash as a reference. You can also consider [reproducible builds](https://repro[ducible-builds.org/).